# How to get url instead of base64 value from img tags

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I'm quite new regarding to the web realm and in an attempt to make my way into it today I started using Beautiful Soup and requests module. Program was going well until code execution gets on (**line 78**) whereon an error is raised because the source value of img tags is retrieved as base64 format. So far, I'm aware that this could be overcome by just encoding it to ascii then decoding it with base64 decoder, but the thing is that **i want it as an URL value**. How should i go about it?

**NOTES:**
(Just in case, one never knows)

1. python version: 3.8.5
2. lxml version 4.6.2
3. beautifulsoup4 4.9.3

**ERROR**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/l0new0lf/Documents/Projects/Catalog Scraping/scrape.py", line 72, in <module>
    webdata['images'].append(requests.get(game_tables[j].select_one(IMG_TAG_SELECTOR)['src']).content)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 640, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 731, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 
'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEHAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=='
```

Any help is welcome, many thanks in advance!!!

**CODE**

```
#CSS SELECTORS FOR LOOKUPS
TITLE_TAG_SELECTOR = 'tr:first-child td.ta14b.t11 div a strong'
IMG_TAG_SELECTOR = 'tr:last-child td:first-child a img'
DESCRIPTION_TAG_SELECTOR = 'tr:last-child td:last-child p'
GENRES_TAG_SELECTOR = 'tr:last-child td:last-child div.mt05 p :last-child'
GAME_SEARCH_RESULTS_TABLE_SELECTOR = 'table.mt1.tablestriped4.froboto_real.blanca'

#CSS CLASS ATTRIBUTE
GAME_TABLE_CLASS = 'table transparente tablasinbordes'

rq = requests.get(
    f'https://vandal.elespanol.com/juegos/13/pc/letra/a/inicio/1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(rq.content, 'lxml')
main_table = soup.select_one(GAME_SEARCH_RESULTS_TABLE_SELECTOR)
print('main_table:', main_table)
game_tables = main_table.find_all('table', {'class': GAME_TABLE_CLASS})
print('game_tables', game_tables)
#help(game_tables)
webdata = {
    'titles' : [],
    'images' : [],
    'descriptions' : [],
    'genres': [],
}


for j in range(len(game_tables)):
    webdata['titles'].append(game_tables[j].select_one(TITLE_TAG_SELECTOR).text)
    print(game_tables[j].select_one(IMG_TAG_SELECTOR)['src'])
    webdata['images'].append(requests.get(game_tables[j].select_one(IMG_TAG_SELECTOR)['src']).content)
    webdata['descriptions'].append(game_tables[j].select_one(DESCRIPTION_TAG_SELECTOR))
    webdata['genres'].append(game_tables[j].select_one(GENRES_TAG_SELECTOR))
    print(titles, images, descriptions, genres, sep='\n')
```

Comment: Hello. That encoded value is a gif, not a url, so requests.get() is going to fail. https://onlineimagetools.com/convert-base64-to-gif

Comment: Hello @JonathanLeon !, that's why i shown the error above in the code and told that i'm aware of how to get it solved, but want to get in return an url value instead, or at least suggest to the server serving the files for it. Though.... i'm not sure whether this is not possible whatsoever!?